# ELKI DBSCAN R* tree index

Tags: r-tree, dbscan, elki

In MiniGUi, I can see `db.index`.  How do I set it to `tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStartTreeFactory` via Java code?

I have implemented:

```
params.addParameter(AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.INDEX_ID,tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory);
```

For the second parameter of `addParameter()` function `tree.spatial...RStarTreeFactory` class not found

```
// Setup parameters:
            ListParameterization params = new ListParameterization();
            params.addParameter(
                    FileBasedDatabaseConnection.Parameterizer.INPUT_ID,
                    fileLocation);
            params.addParameter(AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.INDEX_ID,
                RStarTreeFactory.class);
```

I am getting `NullPointerException`. Did I use `RStarTreeFactory.class` correctly?

Comment: I edited your question for more clarity, but I don't understand what you're trying to say in your last two paragraphs. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELKI command line (and MiniGui; which is a command line builder) allow to specify shorthand class names, leaving out the package prefix of the implemented interface.

The full command line documentation yields:

```
-db.index <object_1|class_1,...,object_n|class_n>
    Database indexes to add.
    Implementing de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.IndexFactory
    Known classes (default package de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.):
    -> tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory
    -> ...
```

I.e. for this parameter, the class prefix `de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.` may be omitted.

The full class name thus is:

```
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory
```

or you just type `RStarTreeFactory`, and let eclipse auto-repair the import:

```
params.addParameter(AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.INDEX_ID,
    RStarTreeFactory.class);
// Bulk loading static data yields much better trees and is much faster, too.
params.addParameter(RStarTreeFactory.Parameterizer.BULK_SPLIT_ID, 
    SortTileRecursiveBulkSplit.class);
// Page size should fit your dimensionality.
// For 2-dimensional data, use page sizes less than 1000.
// Rule of thumb: 15...20 * (dim * 8 + 4) is usually reasonable
// (for in-memory bulk-loaded trees)
params.addParameter(AbstractPageFileFactory.Parameterizer.PAGE_SIZE_ID, 300);
```

See also: [Geo Indexing example in the tutorial folder](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/addons/tutorial/src/main/java/tutorial/javaapi/GeoIndexing.java).

Comment: I am using dbscan and its running fine with out any index. Now when I add "params.addParameter(AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.INDEX_ID, RStarTreeFactory.class)" Its giving a NullPointerError

Comment: @erich-schubert.  The link is broken. Could you fix it? Also could you please show an example on how to use the cover tree index? I would like to do geospatial data for some kind stations/poles.

Comment: Just look around in the sources. For example, the "tutorial" folder. https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/addons/tutorial/src/main/java/tutorial/javaapi/GeoIndexing.java